# Change laravel elixir version path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-elixir

I am using laravel elixir and assign version like that

```
mix.version([
    'public/assets/css/all.css',
    'public/assets/js/all.js'
]);
```

And I call it in meta tag like that

```
{{ elixir('assets/css/all.css') }}
```

The result in meta tag is

```
 <link href="/build/assets/css/all-5ca511c0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I would like to learn is there any way to chang path like

```
<link href="assets/css/all-5ca511c0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Shortly I want to remove "build" from path. Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how `elixir()` helper function is done, at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php`:

```
if ( ! function_exists('elixir'))
{
    /**
    * Get the path to a versioned Elixir file.
    *
    * @param  string  $file
    * @return string
    */
    function elixir($file)
    {
        static $manifest = null;

        if (is_null($manifest))
        {
            $manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents(public_path().'/build/rev-manifest.json'), true);
        }

        if (isset($manifest[$file]))
        {
            return '/build/'.$manifest[$file];
        }

        throw new InvalidArgumentException("File {$file} not defined in asset manifest.");
    }
}
```

### Approach 1

As you can see, it only defines this function if it doesn't exists. 
So one way to go about it would be to define it with your own custom code and make sure that composer autoloader loads it first. But, it can get a little bit trick, so I suggest another approach:

### Approach 2

**Create your own helper function** (with another name)!
Just name it whatever you want, remove the two `build` references and use it. And also, make sure to check the original function from times to times to make sure that your code is compliant.

Answer (score 2):

As of Laravel 5.2, Elixir has an option to set a custom path but it is not documented. To use the public folder without a build subfolder, you could use:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.version(['css/all.css', 'js/all.js'], 'public');
});

// For referencing the css
// null -> base directory (public)
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('css/all.css', null) }}">
```

[This blogpost](https://dotdev.co/handling-assets-versioning-efficiently-with-laravel-elixir-2a8e18459b69#.iybpqw2d6) gives a nice explanation and a workaround for Laravel versions prior to 5.2.